# Show every positive integer can be written in one of the forms $3k$, $3k+1$, $3k+2$ for some integer $k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

Working with Lang, Serge. "Basic Mathematics" (p.40, exercise 10). I will prove one of the lemmas present in the exercise using Fitch-style natural deduction system.

**Lemma 1**: Every positive integer can be written in one of the forms $3k$, $3k+1$, $3k+2$ for some integer $k$.

**Proof of Lemma 1**:

$
\fitch{1.\, \forall x \forall y((x \in \mathbb{Z} \land y \in \mathbb{Z} \land x > 0 \land y > 0) \to \exists! q \exists! r(x = qy+r \land 0 \leq r < y)) \\ 2.\,(3 \in \mathbb{Z} \land 3 > 0)}{
 \fitch{3.\, a \in \mathbb{Z} \land a > 0}{
   4.\,\forall y((a \in \mathbb{Z} \land y \in \mathbb{Z} \land a > 0 \land y > 0) \to \exists! q \exists! r(a = qy+r \land 0 \leq r < y)) \Ae{1}
   5.\, (a \in \mathbb{Z} \land 3 \in \mathbb{Z} \land a > 0 \land 3 > 0) \to \exists! q \exists! r(a = 3q+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \Ae{4}
   6.\,a \in \mathbb{Z} \land a > 0 \land 3 \in \mathbb{Z} \land 3 > 0 \ci{3,2}
   7.\,\exists! q \exists! r(a = 3q+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \ie{5,6}
   8.\,\exists q(\exists! r(a = 3q+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \land \forall q'(\exists! r(a = 3q'+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \to q=q')) \qquad \text{Abbreviation}\\
   \fitch{9.\, \exists! r(a = 3k+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \land \forall q'(\exists! r(a = 3q'+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \to k=q')}{
   10.\,\exists r((a = 3k+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \land \forall r'((a=3k+r' \land 0 \leq r' < 3) \to r=r') \land \forall q'(\exists! r(a = 3q'+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \to k=q') \qquad \text{Abbreviation}\\
   \fitch{11.\, (a = 3k+s \land 0 \leq s < 3) \land \forall r'((a=3k+r' \land 0 \leq r' < 3) \to s=r') \land \forall q'(\exists! r(a = 3q'+r \land 0 \leq r < 3) \to k=q')}{
   12.\,a=3k+s \land 0\leq s<3 \ce{11}
   13.\,0\leq s<3 \ce{12}
   14.\,s=0 \lor (s=1 \lor s=2) \qquad \text{Abbreviation}\\
    15.\,a=3k+s \ce{12}
    \fitch{16.\, s=0}{
     17.\,a=3k \qe{16,15}
     18.\,a=3k \lor (a=3k+1 \lor a=3k+2) \oi{17}
}\\
\fitch{19.\, s=1 \lor s=2}{
 \fitch{20.\, s=1}{
 21.\,a=3k+1 \qe{19,15}
 22.\,a=3k \lor (a=3k+1 \lor a=3k+2) \oi{21}
}\\
\fitch{23.\, s=2}{
 24.\,a=3k+2 \qe{23,15}
 25.\,a=3k \lor (a=3k+1 \lor a=3k+2) \oi{24}
}\\
26.\,a=3k \lor (a=3k+1 \lor a=3k+2) \oe{19,20-22,23-25}
}\\
27.\,a=3k \lor (a=3k+1 \lor a=3k+2) \oe{14,16-18,19-26}
}\\
28.\,a=3k \lor (a=3k+1 \lor a=3k+2) \Ee{10,11-27}
29.\,\exists y(a=3y \lor (a=3y+1 \lor a=3y+2)) \Ei{28}
}\\
30.\,\exists y(a=3y \lor (a=3y+1 \lor a=3y+2)) \Ee{9,10-29}
}\\
31.\,(a \in \mathbb{Z} \land a > 0) \to \exists y(a=3y \lor (a=3y+1 \lor a=3y+2)) \ii{3-30}
32.\,\forall x((x \in \mathbb{Z} \land x > 0) \to \exists y(x=3y \lor (x=3y+1 \lor x=3y+2))) \Ai{31}
}
$

Does it correctly show this proposition holds ?

Is the conclusion a disjunction of three statements ? Is my usage of **Existential Introduction** appropriate in order to accomplish the end goal ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Bernard, I added further details to my question.

Comment: Are you supposed to be aware of Euclidean division?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you clarify ?

Comment: The proof of the lemma with Euclidean division is one-lined, since the constant terms are just the remainder of Euclidean division by $3$, and $k$ is the quotient.

Comment: Isn't my line 1 the statement of Euclidean division ?

Comment: Would be interesting to see how the proof of this lemma could be accomplished in one line. Cannot immediately see how to do it.

Comment: You just have to use that the remainder is nonnegative and less than the diviso, hence here, in formula: $0\le r \le 2$.

Comment: Thank you. So, that proof would start with this theorem as: $(a \in \mathbb{Z} \land 3 \in \mathbb{Z} \land a > 0 \land 3 > 0) \to \exists! q \exists! r(a = 3q+r \land 0 \leq r < 3)$ and then, as $q$ and $r$ are unique, $0 \leq r \leq 2$ and so $a=3k+0 \lor a=3k+0 \lor a=3k+2$. Would be something like that ?

Comment: Yes – almost: the remainder would be $0$ in only one case.

Comment: Thank you. I made a typo.